# How to make a 100% sure conditional update of a Redis key without lua?

Tags: sql, database, redis, nosql, key-value

I want to update a Redis key, but only if its value by the time of the update is equal to certain value.

Similar question has been asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906778/conditional-redis-set-only-update-with-newest-version) and what I found were suggestions about a Lua script, which I am not into.

I found [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/redis/comments/8pirpo/extend_key_value_update_condition_if_the_value_is/) on Reddit, suggesting the following:

1. `GET` X
2. If value is `A` then `WATCH` X
3. `MULTI`
4. `SET` X to `B`
5. `EXEC`

At first glance, this looks good, because if the key gets update by another process anywhere between `WATCH` and `EXEC`, Redis will abort the transaction.

However, when I thought more about it, I came up with the question:

**What if the key gets updated between  `GET` and `WATCH`?**

Is there a way to update the key only if it's 100% sure that at the time of the transaction it holds a certain value, and achieve this only by using Redis commands, as one would do it in SQL with an

```
UPDATE ...
    CASE ...
        WHEN ...
        THEN ...
```

statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's best to use Lua script but if you insist on not using it, you may consider using redlock to lock the resource while you update it. any attempt to update the value will fail during the time you lock, given that the update process is also using redlock

you can change `retryCount` and `retryDelay` and other options to fit with your use case

example with [redlock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redlock)

```js
// the string identifier for the resource you want to lock
var resource = 'locks:account:322456';

// the maximum amount of time you want the resource locked in milliseconds,
// keeping in mind that you can extend the lock up until
// the point when it expires
var ttl = 1000;

redlock.lock(resource, ttl).then(function(lock) {

    // ...do something here...

    // unlock your resource when you are done
    return lock.unlock()
    .catch(function(err) {
        // we weren't able to reach redis; your lock will eventually
        // expire, but you probably want to log this error
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: can you explain me what is account,322456 here?

Comment: @PolaiahBodeddula it's just an example of a unique id of the resource you're trying to lock.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do it having the check done at the server with commands only. It has been discussed and discarded precisely because of Lua scripts being suitable for the purpose. See the [discussion here](https://www.reddit.com/r/redis/comments/8pirpo/extend_key_value_update_condition_if_the_value_is/)

This can be done with Lua scripting in a one-liner `EVAL` command:

```
EVAL "if redis.call('get', 'myKey') == 'expectedVal' then return redis.call('set', 'myKey', 'newVal') else return redis.error_reply('myKey has changed!') end" 0
```

"Redis guarantees that a script is executed in an atomic way: no other script or Redis command will be executed while a script is being executed" [EVAL command docs](https://redis.io/commands/eval)

The Lua script has better performance than doing [Optimistic locking using check-and-set](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#cas). If there are race conditions, it is better to do check and set on an atomic operation to decrease the probability of losing the race.

Comment: What is the difference between checking the value before updating it in Lua as opposed to doing the same by Redis? What guarantees un Lua, that is not guaranteed in Redis, that the value will not get updated between the get check and the set?

Comment: Edited the answer to clarify Lua scripts are atomic - thanks!

Comment: Yep, that's the way I'd do it.

Answer (score 4):

Although transaction is NOT recommended, you can still use it to achieve your goal, i.e. **watch the key before any other operations**.

```
1. WATCH X
2. GET X
3. if value is not equal to A, UNWATCH X and abort
4. MULTI
5. SET X B
6. EXEC
```

Comment: what a brilliant simplicity, so close to mind! Why going for a transaction is not recommended?

Comment: Lua script is better, and transaction might be deprecated in the future, check [the doc](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#redis-scripting-and-transactions) for detail.

Comment: You can save the dict into Redis

Comment: @for_stack Complete nonsense!

Transactions won't be deprecated. Lua integration and transactions are completely orthogonal features.

Comment: @GreenScape Please check [this](https://github.com/redis/redis-doc/commit/e7b4a464e7b1d62928034408ec61df380acac0d8#diff-e3ef41933d61d9ec97be7fcba25283a0dc7f417269a241ec5ac431c7f87037ceL256-L258) change. I'm not sure if Redis community has changed their mind.

Comment: It will never happen for a simple reason: transactions will always be much faster. Lua has overhead, even if it seems small in non-highly-loaded projects.