# Conditional Redis update from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, redis, lua, jedis

how are you doing?

I'd like to know if there is a recommended way to perform a conditional update on redis from spark.

Basically, what I want to do is:

- Given a spark dataframe with columns *key*, *hash_field*, *value*, *value_version*.
  For each row in the spark dataframe, I'd like to check whether the corresponding key exists in Redis. If not, run *hset key hash_field hash_field+version value_version*
- If it does exist, I'd like to only update the value and value version if the version in my spark dataframe is higher than the version in the redis hash field.

I've searched for this, and the most similar question I found was this -> [Conditional Redis set / only update with newest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906778/conditional-redis-set-only-update-with-newest-version)

However, this involves writing and running a Lua script. While I'm fine with that, I wonder what would the best course of action be. Is there a recommended way to do this conditional upsert from spark? If Lua is indeed the way to go, what's the best way to do so from spark? Is it possible using [spark-redis](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis), or should I go down a level and use Jedis directly for each row?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can also try watch along with HSET command.

Comment: Answered on Github https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/issues/260